# multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, scientific-computing

What are the simplest way to use all cores off a computer for a python program ? In particular, I would want to parallelize a numpy function (which already exists). Is there something like openmp under fortran in python ?

Comment: http://packages.python.org/joblib/

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) library. It even allows to spread work across multiple computers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do and how numpy is compiled on your machine (in some cases, some multicore use will be automatic).  See [this page](http://www.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not fit to your specific problem you want to solve, but I personally find the [ipython](http://ipython.org) shell's parallel infrastructure quite attractive. It is relatively easy to set up an ipcluster on localhost (see [in the manual](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_process.html#using-ipcluster)).

You can wrap your function you wish to evaluate into a `@parallel` decorator for example and its evaluation will be distributed among many cores (see the [Quick and easy parallelism](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html#quick-and-easy-parallelism) section of the manual)